# pyalgotrade can not procee csv feed in strategy

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, pyalgotrade

I am trying to load 1- minutes data into pyalgotrade. The feed is loaded correctly but I have some weird error in initializing strategy. Anyone can give some advice on this?
Here is the code

```
class MyStrategy(strategy.BacktestingStrategy):
    def __init__(self, feed, instrument):
        super(MyStrategy, self).__init__(feed)
        self.__instrument = instrument
        self.__rsi = rsi.RSI(feed[instrument].getCloseDataSeries(), 14)
        self.__sma = ma.SMA(self.__rsi, 15)
        self.__instrument = instrument

    def onBars(self, bars):
        bar = bars[self.__instrument]
        # self.info("%s %s %s" % (
        #     bar.getClose(), safe_round(self.__rsi[-1], 2), safe_round(self.__sma[-1], 2)
        # ))
        self.info(bar.getClose())

feed = csvfeed.Feed("datetime", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
feed.addValuesFromCSV("E:\\TD\\Minutes\\CME.csv")
myStrategy = MyStrategy(feed, 'CME')
myStrategy.run()
```

Here is csv

```
open,high,low,close,volume,datetime
206.1,206.1,206.1,206.1,300,2020-02-28 08:10:00
208.87,208.87,208.87,208.87,110,2020-02-28 08:14:00
206.1,206.1,206.1,206.1,164,2020-02-28 08:15:00
207.0,207.0,207.0,207.0,200,2020-02-28 08:17:00
206.0085,206.0085,206.0,206.0,500,2020-02-28 08:19:00
```

here is the error message

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/TD/Backtest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/TD/Backtest.py", line 40, in <module>
    myStrategy = MyStrategy(feed, 'CME')
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/TD/Backtest.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.__rsi = rsi.RSI(feed[instrument].getCloseDataSeries(), 14)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyalgotrade\feed\__init__.py", line 116, in __getitem__
    return self.__ds[key]
KeyError: 'CME'
```

Answer (score 0):

I find out I use the wrong type of feed. Use Barfeed and it works!

```
feed = GenericBarFeed(Frequency.MINUTE)
feed.addBarsFromCSV("APTV", "E:\\TD\\Minutes\\APTV.csv")
myStrategy = MyStrategy(feed, 'APTV')
myStrategy.run()
```